# How Do Upload With angularjs In Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, codeigniter

im sorry mr im try this code for upload with angular in codeigniter but file and data not insert to database and file not upload, :)
please corectly im no find that tutorial in google please..

```php
        $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
        $data = json_decode($postdata);

        $config['upload_path']      = 'assets/img/img_berita/';
        $config['allowed_types']    = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size']         = '1000';
        $config['max_width']        = '1024';
        $config['max_height']       = '768';
        $config['encrypt_name']     = TRUE;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if( ! $this->upload->do_upload($data($_FILES['file'])) ) {
            $this->set_model->update_data('berita', array('gambar' => $data['file']['name']), array('id_berita' => $data['id_berita']) );
            echo '{"stat" : "Success!"}';
        } else {
            echo '{"stat" : "Try Again!"}';
        }
```

```php
    app.controller('berita_uploadImage', function($scope,$http,$routeParams,$location,Upload) {
        $scope.ImageInfo = 
        $scope.dataInfo = [];

        $scope.onFileSelect = function(file) {
            //console.log($scope.picFile);
            if (!file) return;
            console.log(file);
            Upload.upload({
                method : 'POST',
                url : '<?php echo base_url();?>home/dashboard/admin/upload_image_berita',
                data : JSON.stringify({'id_berita':$scope.id_berita,file:file}),
            }).success(function(data) {
                console.log($scope.id_berita);
                console.log(file);
                console.log(data.stat);
            });
        }

        $scope.id_berita = $routeParams.id_berita;
        $http.get('<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/dashboard/admin/getImage_berita/' + $scope.id_berita ).success(function(result) {
            $scope.dataInfo = result;
        });
```

Comment: Please clarify your question

Comment: here is your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487212/angularjs-file-upload-with-php

Comment: i try it but not work. :)

Comment: Here you can find a vary useful tutorial.<br/>
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_upload_file.htm

Comment: im have problem in my source code mr :)

Comment: i don't test it but this may help https://github.com/firmanJS/Upload-Image-Angularjs-Codeigniter