# Angular/PHP: upload file data in $_POST, not $_FILES

Tags: php, angularjs, forms, post

I'm using **AngularJS v1.6.1,** **Apache 2.4.10** on Debian with **PHP 5.6.24** and I'm trying to upload a file to my server using `$http` POST service.
On my `php.ini`, max file size is set to 8Mo, max post size too, upload file is on, and memory size limit is set to 128Mo.

**Form:**

```
<input type="file" accept="application/pdf" id="uploadOT" max-files="1" ng-model="uploadOT" name="uploadOT" valid-file required ng-class="{'md-input-invalid':uploadForm.uploadOT.$error.validFile}" />
```

**Angular directive:** (when input content change, get a FileReader object and send file)

```
myModule.directive('validFile', function() {
    return {
        require:    'ngModel',
        link:       function(scope, elt, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$setValidity('validFile', elt.val() !== '');
            elt.bind('change', function() {

                var file = document.getElementById('uploadOT').files;
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    scope.sendFile(reader, scope.id);
                };
                scope.showUploadProgress = true;
                scope.filename = file[0].name;
                reader.readAsBinaryString(file[0]);

                ctrl.$setValidity('validFile', elt.val() !== '');
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(elt.val());
                    ctrl.$render();
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**Inside controller:**

```
$scope.sendFile = function(reader, id) {
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('id', id);
    fd.append('file', reader.result);
    fd.append('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 8 * 1024 * 1024);
    $http.post('api/upload.php', fd, {
        headers:            {'Content-Type' : undefined },
        transformRequest:   angular.identity
    }).then(function() {
        alert('upload success');
    }, function() {
        $scope.showUploadError = true;
        $scope.showUploadProgress = false;
        $scope.postError = 'Une erreur inconnue est survenue !';
    });
};
```

On server side (file `api/upload.php`), I print variables `$_POST` and `$_FILES` with `print_r()`.

**Why is `$_FILES` always empty, and my file data is in `$_POST['file']`?**

I can create file from `$_POST['file']` data with php function *`file_put_contents()`* but I cannot make verifications that I can make with *`$_FILES`*. Is it really important (security issues)?

If I change my POST `Content-Type` to `multipart/form-data`, the same thing happend.

Comment: check the answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20487212/angularjs-file-upload-with-php

Comment: @num8er: I'm not using 'ng-file-upload' and cannot use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it works, I had to do these modifications:

**Directive:**

```
myModule.directive('validFile', function() {
    return {
        require:    'ngModel',
        link:       function(scope, elt, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$setValidity('validFile', elt.val() !== '');
            elt.bind('change', function() {

                var file = document.getElementById('uploadOT').files;
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    scope.sendFile(file[0], scope.OT);  ////CHANGE HERE
                };
                scope.showUploadProgress = true;
                scope.filename = file[0].name;
                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file[0]);      ////CHANGE HERE

                ctrl.$setValidity('validFile', elt.val() !== '');
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(elt.val());
                    ctrl.$render();
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**Inside Controller**

```
$scope.sendFile = function(file, id) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('id', id);
        fd.append('file', file);
        fd.append('MAX_FILE_SIZE', 8 * 1024 * 1024);
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'upload.php',
            data: fd,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined, 'Process-Data': false},
            transformRequest: angular.identity
        }).then( function() {
            console.log('success');
        }, function() {
            console.log('failure');
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume it's because you forgot to specify the encoding type of your form element.

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

So, by **default** - the browser will assume that the form encoding type is "**application/x-www-form-urlencoded**" which does not support files in this way. You can still securely send file binary data with the stock encoding method however, this might be where performance and functionality are determining factors to which you choose. I recommend running some tests to confirm which is the fastest. In some cases, the difference will be negligible and will likely be for sake of consistency.

Comment: When I show my headers, the request is with Content-Type multipart/form-data, and the data of the request encoded properly... not application/x-www-form-urlencoded...

Comment: Try adding it, and also add method="post" to the element as well. Then vardump $_FILES.

Edit: Also, check your php ini to ensure that "file_uploads" is on.

Comment: What about "file_uploads" option in your ini?

Comment: As I said in my question, file_uploads is 'On'

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. Can you show me the entire post form (or at least the inputs)?

Comment: The input in the question is the only one on the form, and I think that the form is irrelevant here, because I put my data manually in a FormData object, and dont submit the form itself

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134006/discussion-between-timothy-wood-and-ayak973).

Answer (score 0):

Skip the FileReader API and use the `file` object directly:

```
<input type=file files-input ng-model="files" ng-change="upload()" />
```

**The `filesInput` Directive**

```
angular.module("myApp").directive("filesInput", function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function linkFn (scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
      elem.on("change", function (e) {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(elem[0].files, "change");
      });
    },
  };
});
```

**The `upload()` function**

```
 vm.upload = function() {

    //var formData = new $window.FormData();
    //formData.append("file-0", vm.files[0]);

    var config = { headers: { "Content-Type": undefined } };

    $http.post(url, vm.files[0], config)
    .then(function(response) {
      vm.result = "SUCCESS";
    }).catch(function(response) {
      vm.result = "ERROR "+response.status;
    });
  };
```

The [XHR API send()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) method can post either a `file` object or a `FormData` object. It is more efficient to send the `file` object directly as the XHR API uses [base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) for the `FormData` object which has a 33% overhead.

The [DEMO on PLNKR.](https://plnkr.co/edit/ACUr4gNHcKnwi5i5klAr?p=preview)

Comment: Can you tell me where your variable *vm* come from? And what if I have other values to send, I suppose that I have to use FormData?